Authenticate flutter app using website which has no API and OAuth
I have an app where I need to authenticate using other website.
Let me explain through scenario:

Website is for (for example: hashnode.com). btw I can't mention the website as its privacy matter.

It has no API and OAuth like Google Authentication.

App takes users inputted email and password, and check it against sign ins on hashnode.com/signin

Then if the login credentials are valid on website, then app will be login otherwise it will not login.


Now I need to do the thing and don't how to authenticate with flutter against the respective website?
Should I use http or dio? What are process and alternative to do this?
Thankyou
I have an app where I need to authenticate using other website.
Now I need to do the thing and don't how to authenticate with flutter against the respective website?
Should I use http or dio? What are process and alternative to do this?
Thankyou

1st solution: In my opinion if you have access to website apis for login, then make ui in flutter same as website and make api request to website backend via its api using http or dio package.
2nd solution: Above one is the best solution or if you want to do extra work with low performance you can use flutter_webview and JavaScript channel for that. I will not recommend this but you can try
First create a webview and a Javascript channel in it.
After login in  the website emit JWT token from website and the channel will receive that token on flutter app. Store that token and use it as you wish.
flutter side
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class WebViewPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: WebView(
        initialUrl: 'https://yourwebsite.com',
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        javascriptChannels: <JavascriptChannel>[
          JavascriptChannel(
            name: 'channel1',
            onMessageReceived: (JavascriptMessage message) {
              // Handle JWT received from website
            },
          ),
        ].toSet(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

on Website after login emit the token to flutter channel using below code
window.flutter.postMessage(JWT);

When you emit the JWT from website, Javascipt channel will receive it on flutter side and you can use that.
In the second solution you need to do extra work on website that's why i recommend the 1st solution

I dont have an API and OAuth for that website as websites dont support such thing, so Second option is noted and thankyou. I will give it a try.
